# How to logon to Win 10, if there is no password field?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, login-screen

Everytime I boot up my PC Win10 takes a little longer than it used to and opens my lockscreen. The trouble now: There is no fied to input a password. Not even my regular username is displayed.
I already exchanged Utilman.exe with a console. So far so good.
Now i can open a standard version of explorer.exe and make use of the taskmanager.
I never had something like this before and I am hoping to get some advice on how to approach this.

A new and fresh install of Windows could be a solution but i'd prefer not to.

Additional Info:
the console opens as: nt-authorität\system (probably nt-authority in english)

Comment: What is displayed on lockscreen? Try pressing [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Delete]

Comment: The image of the lockscreen, and in the bottom right corner: keyboard layout / network status / Utilman.exe (now a console) / power button. If I wait a few seconds it shows the date and time in the bottom left corner and the network status in the bottom right

Comment: Can you type something or Drag the Lockscreen Up? Actually Lockscreen will move up revealing the input textbox

Comment: What happens if you click on the lockscreen? It should then show you the login screen. I think it does this when there are more than 1 users accessible.

Comment: Well I CAN type . . . but i cant see it, and the lockscreen image is fixed. But when it switches from the time and date display to the regular screen the screen swipes up

Comment: @LPChip, yes it does. but the screen doesnt show me a username or a password field

Comment: What does the regular screen after swiping up show?

Comment: Maybe silly question, but have you actually restarted the pc using Shurtdown -r -t 0? It could be that somekind of process hang, and shutting down does execute a suspend, instead of complete power off.

Comment: It shows the lockscreen image, in the bottom right corner: keyboard layout / network status / Utilman.exe (now a console) / power button.

Comment: What happens if you press [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Delete] on lockscreen?

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: How long is this problem going on? Have you considered reverting to an earlier configuration? The Creative Update is a major update which will refresh lots of system components. If you haven't already updated, you could update and it possibly fixes the problem. Also if you have updated and the problem started since then, you can revert the update and update again.

Comment: Also, what happens if you add a new user to the system, and reboot?

Comment: I've already added 2 new users, and they are listet in the lusrmgr window, but nothing changes for the general problem.

Comment: How can i revert the update?

Comment: You didn't add a mention so I missed the text. Anyway to revert an upgrade, go to Settings > Windows Update > Recovery. From there, press the Get Started button on the 2nd item: "Go back to the previous version of windows 10". This can also be done by rebooting into recovery mode.

Comment: @lpchip I tried everything in the time between. Not a single one if Windows own rescue or repair systems have worked.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I was close to `format C:` and install a fresh copy but then I came across this:

[How To Fix Windows 10 Startup Problems 2017 Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RrYhOY-bLA)

Basic steps:

- Restart the PC and cut the power until you get into the windows own repair menu.
- Enter the command line.
- Navigate to `C:\Windows\system32\config`.
- Create a Backup (`MD backup`).
- Fill up that new folder (`copy *.* backup`).
- Change Folder to regback (`CD regback`).
- Move all stuff one directory up (`copy *.* ..`), now hit <kbd>A</kbd> (all files).
- Now exit the console and continue booting into Windows.

This magically fixed all my problems.

Thanks to @LPChip and @AEonAX for taking the time and trying to help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Do note that posting a link to an off-site entry is a bad thing here on SuperUser. If the link becomes invalid in the future, your entire post becomes useless, and will be deleted. Can you instead add the steps you took that fixed it in the post? You can keep the link for reference too, just add a bit of text what you eventually did. If you do, I'll vote it up.

Comment: It's good you solved your problem and want to share the solution. Keep in mind link-only answers may be considered low quality. Your answer will be useless if the clip is removed. For this reason it's advised to give the crucial steps of the solution here.

Comment: @LPChip I just added all steps

Comment: Instead of trying to destroy your hardware by cutting power, you can just use the Advanced Restart feature by holding down Shift while initiating a restart. ;)

Comment: @Daniel B this was my first intention but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue after installing certain updates. Just reboot you computer by clicking the Power button on your Windows lock screen, the login screen will show you the username and password fields after rebooting.

If you install a fresh copy of Windows 10 Creators Update, that problem will never happen again.

Comment: I rebooted the PC probably over 20 times yesterday. The entire entry system seems to be fried. With the help of a Installation Disk I'm able to open another console (X:\Source>) but I can't see a way to keep my windows instalation.